# ¿Qué hacen estas funciones de haskell?

Tags: haskell

Se que la función solo me devuelve un elemento de la lista, pero no logro comprender como lo hace y cuando quito alguno de los 2 parámetros de la función lambda, el programa no compila.

1.- misterio1 lista = foldr (\ x n -> x + 1) 0 lista

2.- misterio2 lista = foldr (\ x y -> 1+y) 0 lista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las funciones `foldr`, `foldl`, `reduce`, etc realizan operaciones de *reducción* de modo que van acumulando operaciones a través de cada uno de los elementos de la lista para dar un resultado. Lo que da es un resultado final, que no tiene porqué ser un elemento de la lista, ni siquiera ser coincidente con el tipo de datos de los elementos.

`foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn]` (aka *"plegado por la derecha"*) recibe tres argumentos:

- `f` función acumuladora (eg: `f x acc =  acc + x`)
- `z` valor inicial
- `[x1, x2, ..., xn]` lista con la que operar

`foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn]` es equivalente a `f x1 (f x2 ... (f xn z)...)`, o sea, se aplica la función sobre el último elemento, se vuelve a aplicar con el penúltimo y el resultado anterior, así hasta llegar al primero que opera con el resultado que se obtiene del resto de la lista. Este hecho de empezar por la derechar hasta llegar al primero es por lo que se dice que "pliega desde la derecha", `foldr`, ya que parece que va plegando la lista hasta quedarse con un solo valor.

Como preguntas en concreto por dos reducciones, veamos cómo funciona:

```hs
misterio1 lista = foldr (\x n -> x + 1) 0 lista
```

Aquí la función acumuladora ignora el primer argumento, es decir, ignora el acumulador. Con cada operación se ignora el resultado de la operación anterior por lo que podemos reducir el cálculo a lo siguiente:

```hs
foldr (\ x n -> x + 1) 0 [] == 0  -- valor inicial
foldr (\ x n -> x + 1) 0 (y:ys) == y + 1
```

Para el otro caso:

```hs
misterio2 lista = foldr (\x y -> 1 + y) 0 lista
```

La función acumuladora ignora el primer argumento, es decir el elemento de la lista. Va a ir sumando 1 al acumulador por cada elemento de la lista, lo que nos dará al final la longitud de la lista:

```hs
foldr (\x y -> 1 + y) 0 ys == length ys
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de gran ayuda tu aclaración.